Getting data from Aksim 2 encoder using UART
I am an electronics engineering student. I am interested in embedded software. I am stuck in a project I want to do in this field, I would be very happy if you could help me. I am trying to get data from the Aksim 2 encoder with stm32f4. For this, I am sending a clock signal to the encoder from the Transmit of the UART. I was expecting to get the data from the encoder using interrupt. I am getting the data, but the data is shifting and changing too much. Thank you in advance for your ideas on how to fix this problem.
I thought about using DMA interrupt but then it would be difficult to process the data. I used UART synchronous but this time I could not transmit anything.
